# MYSQL: Increase value from row to row with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

I would like to add up meter values from month to month. My data looks like this:

```
| Date       | Energy_produced |
--------------------------------
| 2011-01-01 | 12              |  
| 2017-01-02 | 23              |  
| 2017-01-03 | 25              |  
...
| 2011-02-01 | 11              |  
| 2017-02-02 | 12              |  
| 2017-02-03 | 17              |
```

The GROUP BY would result in the SUM of the values "Energy_produced" for each month but I would like the sum to be added to get:

```
| Month   | Energy_produced_added_up |
--------------------------------------
| 2011-01 | 60                       |  
| 2017-02 | 100                      |
```

I read a lot of articles and understood that I could use a variable:

```
set @result := 0;
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(t.Datum_Maand, '%m') AS measurement_month, 
    DATE_FORMAT(t.Datum_Maand, '%Y') AS measurement_year,
    (@result := @result + SUM(t.Geg_Maand)) AS SUMME
FROM tgeg_maand AS t
GROUP BY measurement_year, measurement_month
ORDER BY measurement_year, measurement_month
```

With GROUP BY, the value is not added up. The statement above displays the same result as:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(t.Datum_Maand, '%m') AS measurement_month, 
    DATE_FORMAT(t.Datum_Maand, '%Y') AS measurement_year,
    SUM(t.Geg_Maand) AS SUMME
FROM tgeg_maand AS t
GROUP BY measurement_year, measurement_month
ORDER BY measurement_year, measurement_month
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the summing by month first and then sum the monthly values. For this you will need to make your original query into a subquery:

```
set @result := 0;
SELECT measurement_month, measurement_year,
       @result := @result + monthly_sum AS SUMME
FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.Datum_Maand, '%m') AS measurement_month, 
             DATE_FORMAT(t.Datum_Maand, '%Y') AS measurement_year,
             SUM(t.Geg_Maand) AS monthly_sum
      FROM tgeg_maand AS t
      GROUP BY measurement_year, measurement_month) mm
ORDER BY measurement_year, measurement_month
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries - sorry about my original comment, I misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(t.Datum_Maand, '%m') AS measurement_month, 
    DATE_FORMAT(t.Datum_Maand, '%Y') AS measurement_year,
    SUM(t.Geg_Maand) AS SUMME
FROM tgeg_maand AS t
GROUP BY measurement_year, measurement_month
ORDER BY measurement_year, measurement_month
```